# MySQL/Python -- committed changes not appearing in loop

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

Using MySQL Connector/Python I have a loop that keeps checking a value for a change every 2 seconds.  Without all the meat, here is the loop (the print is there for testing purposes:

```
try:
   while True:
       request = database.get_row(table="states", wherecol="state", whereval="request_from_interface")[0]
       print(request.value)
       time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
# back to normal operation
```

get_row is a simple select query and it returns the namedtuple fetchall (hence the [0] at the end, it will only ever be one row).

The problem is that once it gets the initial value, it keeps returning that value even if I change it.  For example, if it is "0" to start, it keeps printing "0" even if I go to adminer and change it and even if I open a new terminal and change it and commit it.  I've tried setting the query_cache_size to 0, still no luck.  I thought it was a commit problem, but that wasn't it, either.  If I change it and reconnect, I see the change, but I'm not sure why it won't change while in the program.  Any thoughts?

EDIT: in case it comes up, yes I'm closing the cursor and grabbing a new cursor with every call.

Comment: That did it.  If you place that in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) of InnoDB is [REPEATABLE READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read). This means that subsequent consistent `SELECT` statements will read the same snapshot established by the first within a transaction. Though you're opening and closing cursors, you're probably doing that inside a transaction and so you're reading the established snapshot over and over again. Either `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` to end the current transaction so that you can read values committed after the snapshot was taken.